# Sent Zip file through mail in MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have use **ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip** library for creating Zip file it's working fine, but when i have attach this Zip file to mail attachment, mail is not sent due to attached  zip file,

here is code for attaching zip file to mail

```
System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = null;
                try
                {
                    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                    attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream, "test.zip");
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    return false;
                }
```

please know me how i can send zip file through mail?.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream, "test.zip");
```

passes a Stream, but that Stream is empty (there's nothing in `memoryStream`).

If you want to use a MemoryStream, you must read the contents of the ZIP file into memory.  You can also use a FileStream if the ZIP is already on disk.

If using a MemoryStream, be sure and set its position 0.

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Depending on how you are using SharpZipLib, you may have access to a [ZipOutputStream](http://www.icsharpcode.net/CodeReader/SharpZipLib/031/ZipZipOutputStream.cs.html).  If you do, I think you could use that.

Comment: thanks for reply, yes i have zip file on disk can you show me any example how i can use File stream to attach zip file?

Answer (score 0):

There could be lot of reasons for the issue,

1. Check file date & time
2. Size of the file ( Based on server settings)
3. Try different formats (rar,7z, etc)